# tsconfig compiler options - Are target, module and moduleResolution required if I'm using TypeScript only for type checking?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm currently setting up a react with typescript and webpack 5 project from scratch and I've come across this question of whether the below compiler options are necessary if i'm using babel for code generation and typescript for just type checking? I went through the compiler options documentation on the TypeScript website but I couldn't infer the answer for scenario I'm currently working on. I did eject a CRA and found the below options.

```
"target": "ES5",
"module": "ESNext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
```

Comment: did you find an answer to this question?